# Diagrama Físico ER de una Universidad (Entidad-relación)

Tags: base-de-datos, diagrama-er

finalicé hace días un diagrama físico sobre la composición de una universidad, con sus respectivas relaciones y etc. Mi duda como tal es, **¿Puse correctamente el sentido en el que van las 'flechas' que indican la cardinalidad-relación?**, es decir, por ejemplo, en una tabla intermedia la cual surge de una relación de N a M (muchos a muchos), ¿Cuál o cuáles tablas deberían llevar el signo de muchos? ¿la tabla intermedia o las dos tablas que forman la tabla intermedia?, anexo mi diagrama físico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Las tablas intermedias que tienes en tu diagrama las estas utilizando para resolver relaciones muchos a muchos. Una estrategia que puedes usar para saber cual es el sentido de la cardinalidad es preguntarte acerca de esa misma cardinalidad. Te lo ejemplifico con tu diagrama usando materias y estudiantes. Las preguntas serían las siguientes:

Una materia tiene varios estudiantes? Respuesta: Si

Un estudiante tiene varias materias? Respuesta: Si

Por lo que la cardinalidad terminaría siendo al revés de como la has diagramado, terminaría siendo así:

```
materia 1------* materia_estudiante *-------1 estudiante
```

Si no estuvieras usando la tabla intermedia sería:

```
materia *-------* estudiante
```

Ten en cuenta que el asterisco lo estoy usando para representar muchos